# structs and classes in ContentView_Previews

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a struct:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var isComplete: Bool = false
}
```

Also let item: Item

And a class:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false
    @Published var arr = [Item(isComplete: true), Item(isComplete: false), Item(isComplete: true), Item(isComplete: false), Item(isComplete: true), Item(isComplete: true)]
}
```

And @ObservedObject var model: Model

**How to properly put item and model into ContentView_Previews?**

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(
        item: <#Item#>,
        model: <#Model#>
    )
    }
}
```

I don't know what should I do next :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to add code for the `ContentView`. But if it looks like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var item: Item
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        // no matter what here
    }
}
```

you can write this:

```swift
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(item: Item(isComplete: false))
            .environmentObject(Model())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Александр Грабовский. I have edited your answer, because after using your code I still had one error, but after slight modification it works now :)

Comment: Corrected code is: `struct LocksItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LocksItemView(item: Item(isComplete: false), model: Model())
    }
}`

Comment: @mallow, that's because I don't know what is in LocksItemView. And now it's interesting for me, how it should recomputes the body when array in ```Model``` change, what do you user for this behavior?